# new ViewControllers causing Black screen

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I'm adding new view controllers (scenes) via the interface builder. I drop them on the canvas and then create a new view controller subclass (`NewViewController`, this creates two fiels: `NewViewController.h` and `NewViewController.m`).  I then set the "class" under the identity inspector to the newly added view controller (`NewViewController`).

Now when I run the app the initial scene has a button with a segue to the second scene (where `NewViewController` is the "class") and it doesn't load the new scene/view, its just black.  Am I missing a step?

If I remove the class: `NewViewController`, and put it back to the initial view controller (`ViewController`) it displays the page just fine.

I'm following [this guide](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Xcode_Storyboarding_%28iPhone_iOS_5%29)

Comment: Did you connect your custom view controller's view outlet to the view represented in the storyboard scene in IB?

Comment: Probably not, can you elaborate on that please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `loadView` method that Xcode adds for you in the view controller. This method is required when you build you views programatially but is not needed when using XIBs or Storyboards.

Comment: Wow, I new it would be something simple.  Event though it is an empty method it was still hosing the view.  I just removed the -(void)loadView stubs and it works.Thanks Stephen.

Comment: This also happens when you name a property loadView. Whoops! =P

Answer (score 0):

Did you control drag from the button of the first scene to the second scene to set up the segue between the two scenes? do you have something happening when you click on the button?

Comment: I believe u did something wrong in you new viewcontroller - did u make sure it is a subclass of UIViewController when you set up that class?

Comment: yeah, I set up the segue and it was navigating to the second page but didn't look like it was loading anything (hense just being black).  I removed the -(void)viewLoad stub method from the new view controllers ".m"s and it fired right up.