# xcode: creating a viewController for a tab item in StoryBoard results in a black screen

Tags: uiviewcontroller, storyboard, segue, tabview, uitabview

i have a tab bar controller in my storyboard. I have added a third view controller created a tab link for it (segue). When I run the app the third tab shows with all its objects perfectly. Next I create a ThirdViewController.m and .h file .In Identity Inspector I have set the class for my third tab item as ThirdViewController. When I run the app the third tab item just displays a black screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the loadView method that Xcode adds in the view controller. Answer taken here: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517886/new-viewcontrollers-causing-black-screen)